# .eml preview with images in html body

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, eml

**Context**

I'm working on a previewer for .eml files and I have some problems on showing images that are in the html body.

**Actual solution**

I'm able to get the html body as following:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeMessageUtils.createMimeMessage(null, file);
MimeMessageParser parser = new MimeMessageParser(mimeMessage);
body = parser.parse().getHtmlContent();
```

but this is the result:

[image]

html:

```
...
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">Thanks</font><br>
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">Enry</font><br>
<font size="2" face="sans-serif"><br>
</font><br>
<img src="cid:0__=4EBB0EF7DFBA71E78f9e8a93df93869091@local" width="253" height="120">
```

and this is the .eml:

```
...
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">Thanks</font><br>
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">Enry</font><br>
<font size="2" face="sans-serif"><br>
</font><br>
<img src="cid:0__=4EBB0EF7DFBA71E78f9e8a93df93869091@local" width="253" height="120"></body></html>
--0__=4EBB0EF7DFBA71E78f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0EF7DFBA71E7
Content-type: image/gif; 
    name="02430556.gif"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="02430556.gif"
Content-ID: <0__=4EBB0EF7DFBA71E78f9e8a93df93869091@local>
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
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...
```

**Question**

Does someone knows how should I do in order to be able to show the image correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The html content will have references to the images using "cid:" and the Content-ID instead of "http:".  You'll need a way to resolve those URIs to the corresponding parts of the message, or you'll need to rewrite the html content to use new URLs of your own choosing that you can arrange to resolve to the parts of the message.

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is to replace the src with the base 64 content. Still cannot find how to...

Comment: Try [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) or some other library to parse and rewrite the html.